html variable content does not get styling with svelte
I need to dynamically add html content with the use: statement. My problem is that when adding content to innerHTML the content is not correctly styled.
<script>
    const applyHtml = async (node) => {
        node.innerHTML = '<a href="...">new link</a>';
    };
</script>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">One item</a></li>
        <li use:applyHtml>df</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<style lang="scss">
    a {
        background-color: yellow;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>

This is the result :

Thanks for your help!

You should use the {@html ...} syntax to insert HTML code like that. But you will still have problem with styling element coming from there. For that, you need to use the :global() CSS selector.
Styling a {@html...} tag of a Svelte component by ising the in-component <style> tag (Unused CSS selector)
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">One item</a></li>
        <li>{@html '<a href="...">new link</a>'}</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<style lang="scss">
    li :global(a) {
        background-color: yellow;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>



Svelte adds some extra classes to your html to help with the scoping, the a in the markup will become something like <a class="svelte-xyz"> and the a in th e styling becomes a.svelte-xyz
So the a you add by code (which you normally shouldn't do, but I guess this comes from a library or something) doesn't have that class so it doesn't get the styling.
To get around this you can use :global with your styling, this will transform the styling in just a instead. You can keep the scoping by placing it inside the li
li > a:global {

}

